# AJAX 404 Error in Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, view

I'm trying to load the comment for each article on my `index` page using AJAX.

What am I missing here?

Index:

```
 #welcome/index.haml
    - @articles.each do |article|
       = article.title
       - article.comments.each do |comment|
         %comment-content{ :id => "comment-<%= comment.id %>", :class => "comment-block", "data-comment-id" => "<%= comment.id %>"}
```

Controller:

```
#comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { }
    end
  end
end
```

JS:

```
#comments.js
var loadComment;

loadComment = function() {
  return $('.comment-block').each(function() {
    var $comment_block;
    $comment_block = $(this);
    return $.ajax('/comments/show', {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      data: {
        comment_id: $comment_block.data('comment-id')
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return console.log("Worked OK!");
      }
    });
  });
};

$(document).ready(loadComment);

$(document).on('page:change', loadComment);
```

Show:

```
 #comments/show.js.erb
 $('#comment-<%= @comment.id %>').append('j render(@comment.content)');
```

EDIT:

So the console log displays the following link but I guess the correct URL would be `localhost:3000/articles/1/comment/1`

How do I fix it?

Console log:

```
http://localhost:3000/show?comment_id=%3C%25%3D+comment.id+%25%3E&_=1457784667124
```

## routes.rb

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments do
  end
end
```

Comment: The URL in your AJAX call, needs to be in the format `/comments/:comment_id/show` -- you need to specify the ID of comment that you want to display

Comment: `[comment.article, comment]` is the right path. How do I define it in the AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your loadComment function to this, it should work --

```
loadComment = function() {
  return $('.comment-block').each(function() {
    var $comment_block;
    $comment_block = $(this);
    comment_id: $comment_block.data('comment-id')
    return $.ajax('/comments/'+comment_id+, {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return console.log("Worked OK!");
      }
    });
  });
};
```

The route for the 'show' action is `/comments/:comment_id`

Comment: if you need to just get the content of the comment, the URL should be `/comments/'+comment_id`

Comment: Did you mean `'/comments/'+comment_id`?

Comment: Yes `/comments/'+comment_id`